# Set age for the Private Messages within Trash folder

Tags: members, messages

If a private messages is being deleted, it stores into Trash folder. Here, I 'd like to set a time limit and after that time, PM might be permanently deleted from Trash.

I was looking for any configuration variable for it but didn't get luck. Could anyone please help me for it.

Comment: anyone please help me ....

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like you have any nice extension hooks for the PM system. What you'll likely need to do is create a custom extension that hooks a member logging in and deletes the 'deleted' messages.

**Step 1** Create an extension that hooks a member login

Here you'll need to hook `member_member_login_single`, see this documentation on how to wrap an extension : https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extensions.html

**Step 2** Check for deleted messages for the user

From Step 1 you should have the members ID (if not it should be in the global vars) so what you can do is execute a query like this to get all the messages from the DB that belong to the user and are deleted (in the trash) :

```
SELECT mc .*,md.* 
FROM exp_message_copies AS mc 
JOIN exp_message_data AS md 
ON mc.message_id = md.message_id 
WHERE mc.message_deleted = 'y' 
AND mc.recipient_id = 2 
AND md.message_date < (UNIX_TIMESTAMP( NOW( ) ) - ( 3600 *12 ))
```

*assuming here that the member ID logging in is `2` and we're looking for messages that are ovef 12 hours old (3600 * 12)*

In EE, we can use ActiveRecord for this :

```
$query = ee()->db->select('mc.*,md.*')
             ->from('message_copies AS mc')
             ->join('message_data AS md', 'mc.message_id = md.message_id')
             ->where('mc.message_deleted', 'y')
             ->where('mc.recipient_id', $memberId)
             ->where('md.message_date <', '(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - ' . $period . ')')
             ->get();
```

*here we assume $memberId is the id for the logging in member, $period is the cut off, so now - 12 hours == 43200*

**Step 3** Delete the deleted messages!

From the code above, we'll have none or more items in the $query record set. We can then iterate these and delete them from the db (`message_copies` table).

```
if ( $query->num_rows() > 0 ){
    foreach ( $query->result_array() as $row ) {
        ee()->db->where('copy_id', $row['copy_id'])
                ->delete('message_copies');
    }
}
```

Voila! The hardest part of this may be building the actual extension!
Hope this answers your questions, I tested this (I didn't create the module, but I did create real PM's and tested the delete code) on EE v2.8.1

<s>One last note, I notice that doing this removes the message from the senders 'send' folder as well. I can't be sure if this was ever copied to the sent folder though! I believe by looking at the code another method would be to replace the delete statement with an update, and update the `message_folder` to 0.</s>
*I did some further checking and the above method won't interfere with sent messages*

After some more looking around, I notice from the PM libraries (check out the `erase` funtion on line 2022ish on /system/expressionengine/libraries/Messages.php) that when messages are deleted you'll need to clean up attachments too (line 2077) and update the message count (line 2097) :

```
$query = ee()->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM exp_message_copies
                         WHERE recipient_id = '{$this->member_id}'
                         AND message_read = 'n'");

$results = ee()->db->query("UPDATE exp_members SET private_messages = '".ee()->db->escape_str($query->row('count') )."'
                            WHERE member_id = '{$this->member_id}'");
```

Comment: Did this help at all Bhashkar? I've added some extra notes regarding sent messages, attachements and message count clean up for you.

Comment: Do I get the bounty if the OP author doesn't click this as the answer? It's only a day left and I need the Rep! I mean its a number that grants very bespoke priviledges, I NEED it!! hah :) Would be nice to have an answer o 2 in my history :)